# Disble keyboard on tab bar swipe flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tab bar in my flutter app. Tab bar view has two screens with two different forms. How ever Im editing a form on 1st tab screen and when I change to the 2nd tabscreen , text field on previous screen is selected. how can i disable keyboard on swipe for tabscreen.

```
tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
tabController?.addListener(() {
  if(tabController!.indexIsChanging){
    FocusScope.of(Get.context!).unfocus();
  }
 });
```

I have tried the above code. But i cant dispose the  keyboard on swipe

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I wish it will solve your problem.

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way, try this simple method to hide the soft keyboard.You should wrap your whole screen in the **GestureDetector** method and **onTap** method write this code.

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```